# Bash: assigning the output of 'times' builtin to a variable

Tags: bash

In a `bash` script I would like to assign the output of the `times` builtin to an array variable, but I found no better way than

```
tempnam=/tmp/aaa_$$_$RANDOM
times > ${tempnam}
mapfile -t times_a < ${tempnam}
```

I write the output to a temp file and read it back in array times_a because pipelines or `$(times)` would execute in a subshell and return the wrong values.

Any better solution without the temp file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fundamental problem that you need to solve is how to get both the execution of `time` and the variable assignment to happen in the same shell, without a temporary file. Almost every method Bash provides of piping the output of one thing to another, or capturing the output of a command, has one side working in a subshell.

Here is one way you can do it without a temporary file, but I'll warn you, it's not pretty, it's not portable to other shells, and it requires at least Bash 4:

```
coproc co { cat; }; times 1>&${co[1]}; eval "exec ${co[1]}>&-"; mapfile -tu ${co[0]} times_a
```

I'll break this down for you:

```
coproc co { cat; }
```

This creates a coprocess; a process which runs in the background, but you are given pipes to talk to its standard input and standard output, which are the FDs `${co[0]}` (standard out of `cat`) and `${co[1]}` (standard in of `cat`). The commands are executed in a subshell, so we can't do either of our goals in there (running `times` or reading into a variable), but we can use `cat` to simply pass the input through to the output, and then use that pipe to talk to `times` and `mapfile` in the current shell.

```
times >&${co[1]};
```

Run `times`, redirecting its standard out to the standard in of the `cat` command.

```
eval "exec ${co[1]}>&-"
```

Close the input end of the `cat` command. If we don't do this, `cat` will continue waiting for input, keeping its output open, and `mapfile` will continue waiting for that, causing your shell to hang. `exec`, when passed no commands, simply applies its redirections to the current shell; redirecting to `-` closes an FD. We need to use `eval` because Bash seems to have trouble with `exec ${co[1]}>&-`, interpreting the FD as the command instead of part of the redirection; using `eval` allows that variable to be substituted first, and then then executed.

```
mapfile -tu ${co[0]} times_a
```

Finally we actually read the data from the standard out of the coprocess. We've managed to run both the `times` and the `mapfile` command in this shell, and used no temporary files, though we did use a temporary process as a pipeline between the two commands.

Note that this has a subtle race. If you execute these commands one by one, instead of all as one command, the last one fails; because when you close `cat`s standard in, it exits, causing the coprocess to exit and FDs to be closed. It appears that when executed all on one line, `mapfile` is executed quickly enough that the coprocess is still open when it runs, and thus it can read from the pipe; but I may be getting lucky. I haven't figured out a good way around this.

All told, it's much simpler just to write out the temp file. I would use `mktemp` to generate a filename, and if you're in a script, add a trap to ensure that you clean up your tempfile before exiting:

```
tempnam=$(mktemp)
trap "rm '$tempnam'" EXIT
times > ${tempnam}
mapfile -t times_a < ${tempnam}
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote this even more, I have learned a lot reading this, really nice answer!

Comment: I found a way around the race condition by first moving the coprocess' output to FD 3: `coproc co { cat; }; times >&${co[1]}; eval "exec 3<&${co[0]}- ${co[1]}>&-"; mapfile -tu 3 times_a; exec 3<&-`
This can be simplified a bit by using `head` instead of `cat` to avoid the need for `eval`: `coproc co { head -n2; }; times >&${co[1]}; exec 3<&${co[0]}-; mapfile -tu 3 times_a; exec 3<&-`

Comment: Here's a cleaner version with no race condition and no temporary file descriptors: `coproc cat; times >&${COPROC[1]}; { exec {COPROC[1]}>&-; mapfile -t times_a; } <&${COPROC[0]}`

Answer (score 2):

[Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371702/6232717) got me very interested in this problem, leading to this solution which has no race condition:

```
coproc cat;
times >&${COPROC[1]};
{
  exec {COPROC[1]}>&-;
  mapfile -t times_a;
} <&${COPROC[0]};
```

---

This is quite similar in underlying structure to Brian's solution, but there are some key differences that ensure no funny-business occurs due to timing issues. As Brian stated, his solution typically works because the bash interpreter starts running the `mapfile` command before the coprocess' file descriptors have been fully closed and cleaned up, so any unexpected delay before or during `mapfile` would break it.

---

Essentially, the coprocess' `stdout` file descriptor gets closed a moment after we close the coprocess' `stdin` file descriptor. We need a way to preserve the coprocess' `stdout`.

In [the man pages for pipe](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), we find:

> If all file descriptors referring to the read end of a pipe have been closed, then a write(2) will cause a SIGPIPE signal to be generated for the calling process.

Thus, we must preserve at least one file descriptor to the coprocess' `stdout`. This is easy enough to accomplish with [Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Moving-File-Descriptors). We can do something like `exec 3<&${COPROC[0]}-` to move the coprocess' `stdout` file descriptor to a newly created `fd 3`<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371702/6232717)</sup>. When the coprocess terminates, we will still have a file descriptor for its `stdout` and be able to read from it.

---

Now, we can do the following:

1. Create a coprocess that does nothing but `cat`.

   ```
   coproc cat;
   ```
2. Redirect `times`'s `stdout` to the coprocess' `stdin`.

   ```
   times >&${COPROC[1]};
   ```
3. Get a temporary copy of the coprocess' `stdout` file descriptor.
4. Close the coprocess' `stdin` file descriptor. <sup>(If using a version before Bash-4.3, you can use the `eval` trick Brian used.)</sup>

   ```
   exec 3<&${COPROC[0]} {COPROC[1]}>&-;
   ```
5. Read from our temporary file descriptor into a variable.

   ```
   mapfile -tu 3 times_a;
   ```
6. Close our temporary file descriptor (not necessary, but good practice).

   ```
   exec 3<&-;
   ```

---

And we're done! However, we still have some opportunities to restructure to make things neater. Thanks to the nature of redirection syntax, this code:

```
coproc cat;
times >&${COPROC[1]};
exec 3<&${COPROC[0]} {COPROC[1]}>&-;
mapfile -tu 3 times_a;
exec 3<&-;
```

behaves identically to this code:

```
coproc cat;
times >&${COPROC[1]};
{  
  exec {COPROC[1]}>&-;
  mapfile -tu 3 times_a;
} 3<&${COPROC[0]};
```

---

From here, we can remove the temporary file descriptor altogether, leading to our solution:

Bash 4.3+:

```
coproc cat; times >&${COPROC[1]}; { exec {COPROC[1]}>&-; mapfile -t times_a; } <&${COPROC[0]}
```

Bash 4.0+:

```
coproc cat; times >&${COPROC[1]}; { eval "exec ${COPROC[1]}>&-"; mapfile -t times_a; } <&${COPROC[0]}
```

---

<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13371702/6232717)<sup>We do not need to close the original file descriptor here, and can just duplicate it, as the original gets closed when the stdin descriptor gets closed</sup></sup>

Comment: Nice to see that you found a way to do this without the race! I love these little shell puzzles.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, good question.

An improvment would be to use mktemp, so that you are not relying on randomness to keep your file unique.

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp aaa_XXXXXXXXXX)
times > "$TMPFILE"
mapfile -t times_a < ${tempnam}
rm "$TMPFILE"
```

Also, I use for instead of mapfile (becuase I don't have mapfile).

```
a=0; for var in $(cat "$TMPFILE"); do ((a++)); TIMES_A[$a]=$var; done
```

But, yeah, I do not see how you can do it without files or named pipes.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to do something similar would be

```
times > >(other_command)
```

It's an output redirection combided with a process substitution. This way `times` is executed in the current shell and the output redirected to a new subprocess. Therefore however doing this with `mapfile` doesn't make much sense, as that command wouldn't be executed in the same shell, and that's probably not what you'll want. The situation is a bit tricky, as you can't have either call to the shell builtins executed in a subshell.